# get value the 1 Object in Angular5

Tags: angular

I want get all values the my Object Month ->

```
 public months: Months = {
        jan: false, 
        feb: false, 
       etc...
    }
```

First my object is false but then my user changed a true, then I need know that month is true.

I don't want do 12 if ...

```
  if (months.jan) { ... }
```

I am trying with

```
   let responseProps = Object.keys(this.months);

   console.log('responseProps ', responseProps ); //I get 0º->jan, 1->feb..
   // but I don't get "true or false"
   for (prop of responseProps) {
       console.log('prop', prop );
    }
```

or with ->

```
 for (prop of this.months) { //Now I get error because this.month isn't array.
       console.log('prop', prop );
    }
```

thanks.

Edit ->

```
public months: Months = {
            jan: false, -> index 0
            feb: false, -> index 1
           etc...
        }

 searchMonth(year: string, selectMonth: number) {

    if (selectMonth === undefined) {
        let obKeys = Object.keys(this.months), prop: string, month: number;
        /*Get first Month*/
        for (prop of obKeys) {
            if (this.months[prop]) {
                month = prop; // HERE I NEED the number of month
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `in` operator to loop over `Objects` instead of `of`.

```js
var months = {
        jan: false,
        feb: true,
    }
    
    for (var eachMonth in months) {
      // in operator will also return true for props in prototype chain, hence the below check
      if (months.hasOwnProperty(eachMonth)) {   
        console.log(eachMonth, months[eachMonth]);
      }
    }

// If you want to use Object.keys()
var obKeys = Object.keys(months); // this will not give props from prototype, so no further check
for (prop of obKeys) {
   console.log('prop: ', prop, ", month index: ", obKeys.indexOf(prop), "value: ", months[prop] );
}
```

Comment: @EduBw: You mean after you get the array using `Object.keys()`??

Comment: Yes, I get the month "feb" but I need index "1" because I need send numbers the month

Comment: my question .... I add " edit " in my question, now You can see the result but I don't get the number the select month.

Comment: @EduBw: thats the edit that I had added: Use: `obKeys.indexOf(prop)` where you need the month index..

Answer (score 0):

Use for in loop.

```
for (key in this.months) {
   console.log('prop', this.months[key] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `this.months[prop]`

```
let responseProps = Object.keys(this.months);
console.log('responseProps ', responseProps);
// but I don't get "true or false"
for (prop in this.months) {
    console.log('prop', this.months[prop]);
}
```